# Multiple Locations Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-mobile

Hey Guys I am new to programming apps with the google maps API, and I can create a map showing a single location just fine, but I get confused when trying to implement a way to map multiple locations. (Not hard coded locations.)

In my app I have two Arraylists one containing latitudes and another containing longitudes.

Any suggestions on how I could create geopints from these lists ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `NumberOfPoints` locations stored in `latitudes` and `longitudes`. 
You could do the following:

```
for(int pointIndex=0; pointIndex<NumberOfPoints; pointIndex++){
   GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudes[pointIndex],longitudes[pointIndex]);
   OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "title", "snipet");
   youOverlayClassHolder.addOverlay(overlayitem);
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) is a great tutorial going what you are exactly looking for (check Part 2: Adding Overlay Items)

Comment: yea my app was based on that tutorial I have worked out a way to have a list of geopoints but im struggling to add that list of geopoints to a list of overlayitems